# Calling javascript method onKeyPress

Tags: javascript, jsp

I was trying to implement a javascript method to be executed on "Enter". Here is the code:

`<input id="qty" class="" type="TEXT"  value="<%=qty%>"  name="qty" onKeyPress="isEnterKey(event,'<%=qty%>', '<%=formName%>')">`

Javascript:

```
function isEnterKey(e,packageMinSize,formName)
{
if(isEnter(e))   // Checking for "Enter"
{
            if (!some_condition) 
            {
        alert("Failed");
        return false;
        }
        else
        {
        alert("Success");
        submitMthod();
        }       
}
}
```

Issue is: If i press Enter, I am getting the `Failed` alert, but the `submitMthod()` is executing. Confused, from where it is getting called.

Form tag like , `<form name='<%=formName%>' method=POST action="myActionPage">`

Comment: did you make sure that the isEnterKey is only called once?

Comment: Put some counter in isEnterKey function to make sure it's called only once.

Comment: Make sure that submitMthod() is called only by isEnterkey() function

Comment: Set a counter. `isEnterKey` is calling only once.

Comment: I put a `e.preventDefault();` to prevent the form submission. Don't know its a right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
function isEnterKey(e,packageMinSize,formName)
{
    if (e.keyCode == 13)   // Checking for "Enter"
    {
                if (!some_condition) 
                {
            alert("Failed");
            return false;
            }
            else
            {
            alert("Success");
            submitMthod();
            }       
    }
}
```

instead of

```
function isEnterKey(e,packageMinSize,formName)
{
if(isEnter(e))   // Checking for "Enter"
{
            if (!some_condition) 
            {
        alert("Failed");
        return false;
        }
        else
        {
        alert("Success");
        submitMthod();
        }       
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

are u getting the "sucess" alert too??

if not submitMthod is gettin cald from some place else or may be form is getting submited ..